# find missing value that was multiplied by

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im trying to figure out how i can find what a number has been multiplied by.

so if you started with $100$ and multiplied it by $0.1$ and then add that to $100$ you will have $110$.

is it possible to reverse this calculation to find what the original base number was ($100$)?

$$\begin{align}
x &= ?\\
y &= x \cdot 0.1\\
z &= x + y = 110\\
a &= 100.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your equation is received value = original value *(1+a). So, a = received value/original value - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Since $z=x+y$ and $y=x\cdot 0.1$, this means that $z=x+x\cdot0.1 = 1.1\cdot x$. This means that, since $z=1.1\cdot x$, this means that $x=\frac{z}{1.1}.$